# Powershell annoyingly asks me to confirm y press with enter. How to confirm with just y click?

Tags: powershell

For example, I have a remove command: `ls|rm -Confirm`

For every single file, I have to press 'y' and enter sequentially. In most shells, it's enough to press just 'y'.  How to avoid it in the PowerShell?

Update: It's not about scripts which I wrote. It's about scripts which other people wrote. I need any hack which can give me such possibility to avoid two keys for ALL scripts in my system.

Comment: I'd use the `-WhatIf` parameter then - examine the output and if all is OK run without it on 2nd pass.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `-Confirm` if you don't want to be prompted? That's what `-Confirm` does: force a confirmation prompt.

If you want to force the action with no prompt, then use the `-Force` option instead.

---

Based on your comments, I have two solutions.

1. Instead of Y, press A. That will respond Y for all items in the current command.
2. Write your script so that you handle the confirmation yourself. For example:

   ```
   $todelete = ls
   $choice = ""
   while ($choice -notmatch "[y|n]"){
       $choice = read-host "Do you want to continue? (Y/N)"
   }

   if ($choice -eq "y"){
       $todelete | rm -Force
   }
   else
   {
       write-host "Canceled!"
   }
   ```

Comment: My question wasn't about Confirm. I need it. I don't want to press keys twice.

Comment: Why don't you push A instead of Y? However, this sounds like http://xyproblem.info/. What is the big picture? What are you actually trying to accomplish or solve?

Comment: The problem is in many places I have to confirm some actions. Not all of them should be confirmed. Just part. It can be any place in the powershell. confirm switch, or bypass security. It doesn't matter. The thing is I am keen on confirming or declining with just one key type and not two.

Comment: "confirming or declining with just one key type and not two". Unfortunately, you're out of luck then. That's just how the PowerShell confirmation prompts work.